# Passing a function with a parameter to child component and sending return value back to parent to be stored in parent state in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please forgive me, I am new to programming and JavaScript/React...

This is the question from my assignment:

> Make a counter application using React and Node.js. The user must have the ability to click a button to increase, decrease, or reset a counter. The app must have the following components: Display, DecreaseCount , IncreaseCount, ResetCount. Pass the appropriate functions to be used and current counter value to each component.

I'm not sure what the point is of creating components for those simple operations. I also don't understand what will make those arithmetical components unique if I'm passing them both a function and a value to work on. But I am assuming the point of the assignment is to show that you can pass state to a child, work on it within the child, and then pass the worked-on result back to the parent to be stored in its state.

Here is the main page, Display.js. 
For now I'm just trying to get the add functionality to work:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import IncreaseCount from './IncreaseCount';
import DecreaseCount from './DecreaseCount';
import ResetCount from './ResetCount';

class Display extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.increment = this.increment.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };
  }

  increment = numToInc => {
    this.setState({ count: numToInc++ });
  };
  decrement = numToDec => {
    this.setState({ count: numToDec-- });
  };
  reset = numToReset => {
    numToReset = 0;
    this.setState({ count: numToReset });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{this.state.count} </h2>
        <IncreaseCount count={this.state.count} operation={this.increment} />
        <DecreaseCount count={this.state.count} operation={this.decrement} />
        <IncreaseCount count={this.state.count} operation={this.reset} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Display;
```

And here is the IncreaseCount component class:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class IncreaseCount extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };
  }

  buttonClick = () => {
    this.setState({ count: this.props.count }); // I am pretty sure this isn't necessary
    this.props.operation(this.state.count);
  };

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.buttonClick}></button>;
  }
}

export default IncreaseCount;
```

It is not throwing any errors but is not changing the value of either the Increase count or the Display count properties. I was expecting both to be changing in lockstep. **My goal is to send the incremented value back to Display to be displayed.** Is there a problem with the way I've written and passed my increment function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `this.props.count` within the `IncreaseCount`

```
class IncreaseCount extends Component {
  buttonClick = () => {
    this.props.operation(this.props.count);
  };
  ...
}
```

A full example might look something like this:

```
class Display extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 0
  };

  increment = numToInc => {
    this.setState({ count: numToInc + 1 });
  };
  decrement = numToDec => {
    this.setState({ count: numToDec - 1 });
  };
  reset = () => {
    this.setState({ count: 0 });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{this.state.count} </h2>
        <Operation
          name="+"
          count={this.state.count}
          operation={this.increment}
        />
        <Operation
          name="-"
          count={this.state.count}
          operation={this.decrement}
        />
        <Operation
          name="Reset"
          count={this.state.count}
          operation={this.reset}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Operation extends Component {
  buttonClick = () => {
    this.props.operation(this.props.count);
  };

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.buttonClick}>{this.props.name}</button>;
  }
}
```

Note that you don't have to pass the counter value to each `Operation` and use a functional `setState`:

```
increment = () => {
  this.setState(prev => ({ count: prev.count + 1 }));
};
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for me. The strangeness of the assignment threw me off; asking for separate components for each operation while passing their defining functions to them from Display does not make sense, but using Operation as a reusable component does. And the use of prev was also helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Using a single component like `<Operation />` is certainly how I'd do it. However, per the requirements of the OP, I'm adding this example that uses all 4 components specified.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class IncreaseCount extends Component {
  render(props) {
    return <button onClick={this.props.action}>+</button>;
  }
}

class DecreaseCount extends Component {
  render(props) {
    return <button onClick={this.props.action}>-</button>;
  }
}

class ResetCount extends Component {
  render(props) {
    return <button onClick={this.props.action}>reset</button>;
  }
}

class Display extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { count: 0 };

    this.increment = this.increment.bind(this);
    this.decrement = this.decrement.bind(this);
    this.reset = this.reset.bind(this);
  }

  increment() {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  }

  decrement() {
    if (this.state.count > 0) {
      this.setState({ count: this.state.count - 1 });
    }
  }

  reset() {
    this.setState({ count: 0 });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{this.state.count}</h2>
        <DecreaseCount count={this.state.count} action={this.decrement} />
        <IncreaseCount count={this.state.count} action={this.increment} />
        <ResetCount count={this.state.count} action={this.reset} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Display;
```

This version also prevents the counter from going below 0.

Comment: Thanks - I was going to adapt the accepted answer into this basic idea for the purpose of accurately addressing the assignment question.  Even though this answers my question, it reflects the illogical nature of the requirements in the question and for that reason I'll leave the accepted answer as is since it actually leverages components in a more logical way. Thanks for your attention to detail, though!